# Como adicionar em um botão a animação para voltar ao topo da página usando a biblioteca easings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transição

A procura de efeitos pra adicionar em um botão tipo "Voltar ao Topo" encontrei essa biblioteca jQuery que utiliza o *transition* do CSS, o SCSS e o próprio jQuery pra fazer animações, mas não consegui adicioná-las ao botão topo, alguém conhece? Ou sabe de outra desse tipo?

Site: http://easings.net/pt

Comment: Você irá importar uma biblioteca inteira apenas para esse efeito? Existe resoluções simples de menos de 10 linhas que faz o que você quer

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas sempre que preciso utilizar animações, faço simulações no site http://css3generator.com.

Comment: @thaináv. não conhecia essa, muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, disponha! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para aplicar easing podes fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).data('target')).offset().top
  }, 800, 'easeOutBounce'); // o easing que queres entra como ultimo argumento
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 600px;
}
#one {
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<button data-target="#one">ONE</button>
<button data-target="#two">TWO</button>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

No teu caso para voltar ao topo mudarias o objeto que entra para o animate:

```
$('BOTAO_PARA_TOPO').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: 0
    }, 800, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

Podes editar e colocar qualquer efeito (easing) [daqui](http://easings.net/pt)

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria, funcionou perfeitamente, é só mudar e tirar o easeOutBounce e colocar qualquer outro efeito que esta no link. Muito obrigado @miguel era exatamente o que queria. Obrigado

Comment: Exato qualquer outro do link também funciona. Ainda bem @ClaytonFurlanetto, de nada

Answer (score 0):

Fiz este código é bem simples de usar:

```
$(function () {
    var $doc = $('html, body');
    $('.ancora').click(function () {
        $doc.animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).position().top
        }, 700);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Você adiciona a class "ancora" no "a" que você quer fazer o efeito da ancora:

Exemplo:

```
<a class="ancora" href="#topo">vai para o topo</a>
```

E no href você coloca para onde ele vai, por exemplo você coloca na primeira div do seu site o id topo.

```
<div id="topo">
```

Assim ele vai ate a div com o id topo.

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/83abc8mq/1/

Se você quiser um scroll horizontal:

```
$(function () {
    var $doc = $('html, body');
    $('.ancora').click(function () {
        $doc.animate({
            scrollLeft: $($(this).attr('href')).position().left
        }, 700);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/83abc8mq/2/

Comment: Esse tipo de efeito já tenho feito, mas queria algo diferente, vc deu uma olhada no link, viu os efeitos? Pela sua resposta acho que vc não viu. Esses efeitos diferentes que estão no link que queria adicionar, pra ficar uma coisa diferente.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto fiz uma edição, mas da para fazer de forma horizontal também e a alteração é bem simples, o trabalho maior nisso tudo é o css.

Comment: Obrigado Wictor nosso amigo Miguel ali embaixo me explicou como usar os efeitos da biblioteca, queria usar ela pois pra cada projeto posso aplicar os efeitos, ainda engatinho no js, valeu pela ajuda.